# union of NP and co-NP, closure under polynomial time reduction

Tags: np, polynomial-time-reductions, co-np

Is $Union = NP\cup co-NP$ closed under polynomial-time many-one reductions?

I understand that in order to be so, for $A\in Union, A \leq_P B $ there should exist a polynomial time computable function $f$ such that:
$x\in A \implies f(x) \in B$. So the function computed for an input from $Union$ is also in $Union$. It looks like a true statement for me, however I miss a formal proof. May I ask for some directions?

Comment: I just gave a random name to this union, didn't know it's already taken. I will update my question, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully I solved it:

let $B \in Union, A <_p B$, then from $ B \in NP \implies A \in NP$ and from $B \in co-NP \implies B \in co-NP$, thus $A \in Union$. So $Union$ is closed under polynomial time reductuons.